# The requested URL /cake/posts/index was not found on this server

Tags: php, cakephp

I was spirited follow the tutorial (create a blog) on the official site of cakephp and I finished the first stages of installation and configuration. But the problem is that I can not have the same design as the tutorial (the error message and success are without color) so I created my PostController with the index function but  it displays "The requested URL / cake / posts / index was not found on this server. "(I follow the tutorial word by word) please help me That I can continue the rest of tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Controller name should be in plural 
So it would be PostsController.php